# Ruby - passing block inside the function parenthesis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently started to learn Ruby on Rails and it is really weird to get used to the syntax of Ruby.

I decided to go with all the parenthesis (that I know from other languages) that can be placed and I got stuck:

```
test "invalid signup information" do
        get signup_path
        assert_no_difference("User.count", {
            user_params = { user: {
                name: "",
                email: "foo@invalid",
                password: "foo",
                password_confirmation: "bar"
            }}
            post(user_path, {params: user_params})
        })
    end
```

I want to pass a block into the assert_no_difference and somehow it is showing me an error during my tests. It started to show it after I places the definition of user_params. As far as I read some websites the syntax is OK, so what might be going wrong?

Comment: Can you updated the question with the error message?

Comment: You'll need a comma between `user_params = {}` and `post(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two general forms for passing in blocks. The long-form way is to use `do` ... `end`:

```
assert_no_difference('User.count') do
  # ...
end
```

There's also the curly brace version:

```
assert_no_difference('User.count') {
  # ...
}
```

Note that the curly brace style is generally reserved for single line operations, like this:

```
assert_no_difference('User.count') { post(...) }
```

For multi-line you generally want to use `do`...`end` since it's easier to spot. The *When in Rome* principle applies here, so you may need to shed some of your expectations in order to do things the Ruby way.

What you're doing wrong is passing in an argument that's presumed to be a Hash, but as it contains arbitrary code that's invalid. Unlike JavaScript the block is defined outside of the arguments to function call.

Cleaning up your code yields this:

```
test "invalid signup information" do
  get signup_path

  assert_no_difference("User.count") do
    post(user_path,
      params: {
        user: {
          name: "",
          email: "foo@invalid",
          password: "foo",
          password_confirmation: "bar"
        }
      }
    )
  end
end
```

Note you can supply the arguments inline, plus any hash-style arguments specified as the last argument in a method call does not need its curly braces, they're strictly optional and usually best omitted.

Comment: So the problem is with the block, and not the associative array, right? Can I include the block inside the function parenthesis as well?

Comment: While technically an "associative array" or "dictionary", in Ruby they're called hashes. The problem is primarily with the block, yes. I've added a cleaned-up version of your code.

Comment: It is going to be a hard way, to switch from Objective C/ Swift to Ruby for some time. Anyway, great explanatory answer! Thanks.

I am going to change the title of this question a little bit so others like me can find it more easily!

Comment: It might not be easy. Ruby leans very heavily on the ability to pass an arbitrary block to a method with minimal syntax required, so it's a good thing to get used to.